# Laravel using domPDF

Tags: php, laravel

I want to download a blade. I am using dompdf.

```
public function download($id)
{
    $booking=Booking::where('id',$id)->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.booking.bookingdetails',$booking);
    return $pdf->download('bookingdetails.pdf');
}
```

**bookingdetails.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Invoice  # {{$booking->id}}
            <strong>01/01/01/2018</strong>
            <span class="float-right"> <strong>Status:</strong> Pending</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is passing the `$booking` variable from the method and send to the view. Then download it as a pdf file.

But the error is:

> "Undefined variable: booking

Answer (score 3):

I'm shooting in the dark here, shouldn't it be:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.booking.bookingdetails', ['booking' => $booking]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an array as the second argument to the view with the index name of `booking` so try this:

`$pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.booking.bookingdetails',['booking' => $booking]);`